# Error in mounting HDD

Tags: partitioning, mount, hardware, hard-drive, ntfs

I am getting the following error whenever I mount my external HDD. It was working before and then I opted for safely removing the drive. Now its giving me following error

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: ntfs_mst_post_read_fixup_warn: magic: 0x43425355  size: 4096   usa_ofs: 8850  usa_count: 65535: Invalid argument
Actual VCN (0x800006009000000) of index buffer is different from expected VCN (0x0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb1': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the most easiest solution was already given in the error message:

> In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot into Windows twice.

If You have Windows, boot to it, select the partition, Right Click -> Properties -> Tools -> Check disk.

Alternatively, You can execute `chkdsk /f Driveletter:` after opening a command prompt with administrative privilege.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have Windows, you can try a Linux program, though:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfsprogs
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: with ntfsfix I get:
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb1
Mounting volume... $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 0...ntfs_attr_mst_pwrite: written=-1: Operation not permitted
Error writing $Mft record(s): Operation not permitted
FAILED
Error correcting $MFTMirr: Operation not permitted